# What is the meaning of "what" in this text?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of "what" in this text?

> Ctesiphon, indeed, was not to Persia **what** it had been to Parthia; but
> still it might fairly be looked upon as a prize of considerable
> importance. Of Parthia it had been the main, in later times perhaps
> the sole, capital; to Persia it was a secondary rather than a primary
> city, the ordinary residence of the court being Istakr, or Persepolis.

From [*The Seven Great Monarchies of the Ancient World*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm), vol. 7, chapter 10, by George Rawlinson.

Comment: The rest of the paragraph explains it. Ctesiphon had been a capital city of Parthia. It was not such an important place to Persia, though it was _quite_ important.

Comment: It means "that which".

Comment: What I am to you is no business of theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite this many ways, but one example would be:

> Ctesiphon, indeed, was not worth to Persia what it had been worth to Parthia.

The construction "is ... to ..." can describe worth, meaning or relationship. For example:

"He is a friend to me".

or

"It is nothing to him".

In your example, the specific relation is not initially given; instead, only a comparison is made. For example, this sentence says that the meaning of the thing is the same for me and you:

"It is to me what it is to you".